# Can I build a RDLC report for my website build on .NET 2.0, using Microsoft rdlc designer 2022?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

My website (.NET 2.0) is built using Visual Studio 2005.

Due to the fact that I can't install VS 2005 on newer versions of Windows (Win 8.1, Win 10), I installed VS 2022 Community to modify my website.

I added Microsoft RDLC designer from marketplace to add new reports. when I tried to compile my website I get this error:

> The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition

What do I need to add or modify to get my website to run?

I tried to get a solution for this problem by installing reportviewer 2008 redist package but the error is still happening

Comment: Did you install a .net core version of the report system, or a .net framework version? Quite sure the .net framework version does not work with a MVC .net  core application. In fact, some real hacks are to be done to get the .net framwork version to work with MVC.  Are you saying that these reports worked in the .net core 2 application, or you NEVER had reports working and want to add the .net reporting the system? (that's a huge and massive difference here). Some hacks exist suggesting reports can work, but we need to know if reports were working. I did not think they work for .net core.

Comment: In ohter words, if those hacks and handstands already been done, and reports were working with the .net core 2.0 application, then they should work with later versions of .net core. However, as noted, if reports were not installed + working before, then I don't think they are going to work now. That client side reporting library is for .net framework, and specifically for .net framework webforms, not MVC, and for sure not .net core MVC applications.

Comment: I think this is not .NET Core.  OP said Visual Studio 2005, which would be .NET _Framework_ 2.0.

Comment: Yes, the website is developed using framework 2.0 (ASPNET and C#) not .Net core NO MVC.